# How to send datetime fields to SFDC using AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

What is the proper way to update DateTime fields in a Salesforce Object using the `UpdateSingleSalesforceObject` function in AMPScript?

Answer (score 3):

I've had success by using the [FormatDate function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/FormatDate.htm) along with the **"iso"** parameter.

```
set @today = FormatDate(Now(),"iso")
```

And here is how it's used in the [UpdateSalesforceObject function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/updatesinglesalesforceobject.htm).

```
set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Contact',@ContactID,'Email','somebody@somewhere', 'Birthdate',FormatDate(Now(),"iso"))
```

Answer (score 2):

I found out recently that Salesforce interprets the date that you send via the API with AMPscript to be in UTC timezone, so you need to make sure you convert your date field to UTC before sending it to SFDC:

```
set @today = Format(DateParse(now(),1), "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.000")
```

Also, make sure to use the ISO format provided below to avoid errors.

Answer (score 0):

Using `DateParse()` I run into errors, so I went with `set @today = FormatDate(Now(),"iso")` and that worked fine. Besides it is shorter / more readable anyway. :-)